# What are good candidate templating languages that are customizable and can be made simple for end-users?

Tags: python, templates, template-engine

I want to have a flexible templating language that I can customize for a specific use case, and also make it simple enough for non-programmers to use. I looked at Cheetah; does anyone have any others and/or any thoughts on customization? Python would be great, but other language-implementations are also OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jija2 is a templating library that I find easy to use

See: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/

See a previous SO question: [What is the fastest template system for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324238/what-is-the-fastest-template-system-for-python)

Comment: @zallarak: Customize templating system? It is open source. I have used it for different kinds of templating from html, text and as well as XML. It is quite generic.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that helps. Is there anything that sticks out about Jinja that contrasts with Cheetah?

Comment: @zallarak: I have found Jinja2 easier to grasp and use

Answer (score 0):

I like [wheezy.template](https://bitbucket.org/akorn/wheezy.template) since it looks very similar to my python code. Its syntax is compact, expressive and clean. I was able to start right after a quick look at example. It amazing how intuitive it is. In addition it is [fast](http://mindref.blogspot.com/2012/10/python-templates-benchmark.html).