# Fastest stdlib approach to PHP-like templating in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, template-engine

The project I'm currently working on requires me to use the Python's built in HTTP server and I need to build dynamic HTML pages on my own. The %REPLACE_ME% syntax in HTML files has recently got too annoying and I'd love to replace it with in-place code as it's done in PHP. Is there any good solution to parsing a string with  (or any other similar syntax) and evaling the code inside?

Edit:

Jon Clements pointed me out that I forgot to explain why would I need the in-place code. There are two reasons - first is that I'm used to such approach, the latter being that I'd like to use some loops and don't want to end myself constructing half of the HTML code for e.g. tables in the model file. The stdlib requirement is because I'd like to keep dependencies as little as possible. I could allow for some really really slim library for that though.

Comment: I don't know PHP.  Are you looking for python's [Template Strings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings)

Comment: You could look into using Django's templating system. It doesn't rely on Django, there is also Mako templates which is a good one [link](http://www.makotemplates.org/)

Comment: @Pjuu apparently "stdlib" is required - still not sure why though

Comment: @JonClements clearly need to get info from the subject and not just the question lol... template strings is probably the best option

Comment: I answered your questions in the edit.

Comment: With the template systems you can use loops inside them to create tables. Have a look at web.py it has a small templating system you could use with a few modifications. The codes not massive so wouldn't be hard to pick it out

Comment: @Pjuu yes - I wanted more information so that it's more useful to other people later on, and also to narrow the question down to a solvable answer - no crime in that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the last comment I will try and outline some options:

Built in to python the best options is the `string` module.

As stated in the comments the documentation is here: [7.1. string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings)

There are a lot of third party templating systems which are incredibly powerful. I am not a big PHP user but you would class these similar to Smarty etc...

[Django Template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/)

There is also a great open source book related to using them [Django Book: Chapter 4 - Templating](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html)

I have never used these outside of Django but I know there is a few frameworks which let you use them. I am not to sure how much work this would be to integrate it with another system but it definitely can be done.

[Mako Templates](http://www.makotemplates.org/)

This is another good templating system which is really powerful. This is used by some big frameworks like Pylons.

[Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/)

This is also a good templating system.

There are a few other discussions around SO about templating systems: [What is the fastest template system for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324238/what-is-the-fastest-template-system-for-python). This is just an example but there is a much bigger list of template systems there.

Answer (score 3):

It can be frustrating at first if you can't execute arbitrary code if you're use to PHP.

You **can** do this though using the [Python CGI](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) module. (but unlike PHP it's meant to be run through an interface rather than something else - WSGI is the way to go here - and not too much setup either).

Now away days it's more traditional to separate program logic from display logic. So that there's "templates" which fill in information from a "view" (which returns information via response objects). It's commonly called "MVC" but not all "MVC"s are "MVC"s.

I still remember PHP from when it was "Project Home Page" - it's evolved a lot, and was a great way to not write C for CGI's... but languages have advanced since then as well as techniques...