# Generating XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm developing an API using Python which makes server calls using XML. I am debating on whether to use a library (ex. http://wiki.python.org/moin/MiniDom) or if it would be "better" (meaning less overhead and faster) to use string concatenation in order to generate the XML used for each request. Also, the XML I will be generating is going to be quite dynamic so I'm not sure if something that allows me to manage elements dynamically will be a benefit.

Comment: Profile, profile, profile.

Comment: Why not use JSON? The module is easy to use, it is a standard for web APIs, and is platform independent.

Comment: I would love you use JSON. Unfortunately, the API I'm using (Authorize.net) is not quite up on the better web technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend that you make use of one of the Python libraries; such as [MiniDom](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html), [ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm), [lxml.etree](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) or [pyxser](http://coder.cl/products/pyxser/). There is no reason to not to, and the potential performance impact will be minimal.

Although, personally I prefer using [simplejson](https://code.google.com/p/simplejson/) (or simply [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)) instead.

```
my_list = ["Value1", "Value2"]
json = simplejson.dumps(my_list)
# send json
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are just using authorize.net, why not use [a library specifically designed for the Authorize.net API](https://github.com/jeffschenck/authorizesauce) and forget about constructing your own XML calls?

If you want or need to go your own way with XML, don't use minidom, use something with an `ElementTree` interface such as [`cElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (which is in the standard library). It will be much less painful and [probably much faster](http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm).  You will certainly need an XML library to *parse* the XML you produce, so you might as well use the same API for both.

It is very unlikely that the overhead of using an XML library will be a problem, and the benefit in clean code and knowing you can't generate invalid XML is very great.

If you absolutely, positively need to be as fast as possible, use one of the [extremely fast templating libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1326219/1002469) available for Python. They will probably be much faster than any naive string concatenation you do and will also be safe (i.e do proper escaping).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/), especially if the dynamic nature of your xml is fairly simple. This is a common idiom in flask for generating html responses.

Here is an example of a jinja template that generates the XML of an aws S3 [list objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) response. I usually store the template in a separate file to avoid polluting my elegant python with ugly xml.

```
from datetime import datetime
from jinja2 import Template

list_bucket_result = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <Name>{{bucket_name}}</Name>
    <Prefix/>
    <KeyCount>{{object_count}}</KeyCount>
    <MaxKeys>{{max_keys}}</MaxKeys>
    <IsTruncated>{{is_truncated}}</IsTruncated>
    {%- for object in object_list %}
    <Contents>
        <Key>{{object.key}}</Key>
        <LastModified>{{object.last_modified_date.isoformat()}}</LastModified>
        <ETag></ETag>
        <Size>{{object.size}}</Size>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>{% endfor %}
</ListBucketResult>
"""

class BucketObject:
    def __init__(self, key, last_modified_date, size):
        self.key = key
        self.last_modified_date = last_modified_date
        self.size = size

object_list = [
    BucketObject('/foo/bar.txt', datetime.utcnow(), 10*1024 ),
    BucketObject('/foo/baz.txt', datetime.utcnow(), 29*1024 ),
]

template = Template(list_bucket_result)
result = template.render(
    bucket_name='test-bucket',
    object_count=len(object_list),
    max_keys=1000,
    is_truncated=False,
    object_list=object_list
)
print result
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <Name>test-bucket</Name>
    <Prefix/>
    <KeyCount>2</KeyCount>
    <MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
    <IsTruncated>False</IsTruncated>
    <Contents>
        <Key>/foo/bar.txt</Key>
        <LastModified>2017-10-31T02:28:34.551000</LastModified>
        <ETag></ETag>
        <Size>10240</Size>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>
    <Contents>
        <Key>/foo/baz.txt</Key>
        <LastModified>2017-10-31T02:28:34.551000</LastModified>
        <ETag></ETag>
        <Size>29696</Size>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>
</ListBucketResult>
```

Answer (score 1):

My real question is what are the biggest concerns for what you're trying to accomplish? If you're worried about speed/memory, then yes, minidom does take a hit. If you want something that's fairly reliable that you can deploy quickly, I'd say use it.

My suggestion for dealing with XML in any language(Java, Python, C#, Perl, etc) is to consider using something already existing. Everyone has written their own XML parser at least once, and then they never do so again because it's such a pain in the behind. And to be fair, these libraries will have already fixed 99.5% of any problems you would run into.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [LXML](http://lxml.de/).  It's a Python library of bindings for the very fast C libraries **libxml2** and **libxslt**.

LXML supports XPATH, and has an [elementTree](http://lxml.de/compatibility.html) implementation.  LXML also has an interface called [objectify](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) for writing XML as object hierarchies:

```
from lxml import etree, objectify
E = objectify.ElementMaker(annotate=False)

my_alpha = my_alpha = E.alpha(E.beta(E.gamma(firstattr='True')),
                              E.beta(E.delta('text here')))
etree.tostring(my_alpha)
# '<alpha><beta><gamma firstattr="True"/></beta><beta><delta>text here</delta></beta></alpha>'

etree.tostring(my_alpha.beta[0])
# '<beta><gamma firstattr="True"/></beta>'

my_alpha.beta[1].delta.text
# 'text here'
```